# How to store Excel file after generation on Laravel storage?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I use this code to generate binary file. How to store it in local storage?

```
$path = 'events/';

$filename = 'visitors_list_' . date('d-m-y') . '.xlsx';

return Excel::import(new VisitorsExport($request), $path.$filename);
```

I use [library](https://github.com/Maatwebsite/Laravel-Excel)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The method is Excel::store().

According to [this](https://docs.laravel-excel.com/3.1/architecture/#storing-the-file)

Beware your return keyword will end the execution

Comment: Could you share sample?